# Column values spread to multiple lines

Tags: bash, parsing

I have a file as follows:

```
1984

32768 5240.70
32768 5259.46
32768 5203.42

2016

32768 5244.38
32768 5223.40
32768 5263.07

2048

32768 5233.59
32768 5241.35
32768 5212.37
```

I want to convert to this format:

```
1984 32768 5240.70
1984 32768 5259.46 
1984 32768 5203.42
2016 32768 5244.38 
2016 32768 5223.40 
2016 32768 5263.07 
2048 32768 5233.59
2048 32768 5241.35
2048 32768 5212.37
```

Can this be achieved easily using bash? Single-line solution will be better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here it is as a one-liner :)

```sh
while read -a arr; do if [ ${#arr[@]} -eq 1 ]; then first=$arr; elif [ ${#arr[@]} -gt 0 ]; then echo $first "${arr[@]}"; fi; done < input_file.dat > output_file.dat
```

You may prefer to use it as a function though which you can store in your `~/.bash_aliases` or `~/.bashrc`

```sh
convert_file() {
    input_file="$1"
    while read -a arr; do               # Each word on line into array "arr"
        if [ ${#arr[@]} -eq 1 ]; then   # Only one item on line
            first=$arr                  # Set "first" value
        elif [ ${#arr[@]} -gt 0 ]; then # Ignore blank lines (more than zero items on line)
            echo $first "${arr[@]}"     # Output "first" value, then line
        fi
    done < "$input_file"                # Feed the read loop with the input file
}
```

and call it like this:

```sh
convert_file input_file.dat > output_file.dat
```

Explanation of the above:

- `$1` this is the first argument from the command line
- `while read -a arr` loops through the input and loads each word on each line into an element in array "arr"
- `[ ${#arr[@]} -eq 1 ]` tests if the length of array "arr" (`${#arr[@]}`) is mathematically equal to (`-eq`) 1 (i.e. we only have one word on the line)
- Arrays are slightly odd in bash.  If you want to look at the whole array, you need the `[@]` and the curly braces - `${arr[@]}`. Preceding the name of the array variable with `#` gives the length
- `first=$arr` - `$arr` is the lazy way to get the first element from the array, but it works :)
- `[ ${#arr[@]} -gt 0 ]` tests if the length of array "arr" (`${#arr[@]}`) is mathematically greater than (`-gt`) zero (i.e. we don't have a blank line)
- `echo $first "${arr[@]}"` outputs the "first" value followed by the contents of array "arr"
- `done < "$input_file"` - `<` sends the contents of a file (in this case `$input_file` from the first line of our function) to the loop or `read` command
- `convert_file ... > output_file.dat` redirects the output from the `convert_file` function to the file `output_file.dat`. NOTE: the file will be truncated first! Use `>>` instead of `>` to append to a given file

Comment: @Kadir hopefully that explanation is useful to you

Comment: a case statement is a little more concise: `case ${#arr[@]} in 0) : ;; 1) year=${arr[0]} ;; *) echo "$year ${arr[*]}" ;; esac`

Answer (score 3):

Same logic as @Kind in `awk`:

```
awk '1 == NF { key=$1 }; 2 == NF { print key " " $0 };' file
```

I like the pure `bash`, but `awk` will be a lot faster and more efficient on a file of any significant size.

And just as an exercise, an implementation in `sed`... >;o]

```
sed -En '/^ *$/d; /^[0-9]{4}$/h; /^[0-9]{5} /{ x; G; s/\n/ /g; p; s/ .*//; h; }' file
```

Broken out and explained:

```
sed -En '        # -E use extended pattern matching. -n only print when requested
  /^ *$/d;       # delete blank lines
  /^[0-9]{4}$/h; # store  header lines

  /^[0-9]{5} /{  # for data lines,
     x;          # swap the hold and pattern spaces
     G;          # add the hold (data) to the pattern (header)
     s/\n/ /;    # remove the newline between
     p;          # print the resulting line
     s/ .*//;    # remove the data
     h;          # put the header back into the hold space
  } ' file
```

Answer (score 1):

Another take, a little state machine:

```sh
awk '
  y || NR == 1 {year=$1; getline; y=0; next}
  NF == 0 {y=1; next}
  {print year,$0}
' file
```

But looking again, it will break with consecutive blank lines.